# downloading/uploading wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I just made my first wordpress theme. I am using c9.io. I downloaded the files and it downloaded as a .tar.gz zipped file, i went to upload to wordpress and got an error saying "The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature"

What does this mean? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: how did you upload it? you should upload it by ftp and then unzip remotely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phew, I got it. I couldnt get the ftp to mount on c9.io, but then uploaded the files using http://www.net2ftp.com/index.php and it worked.